# TYPO3: How can I set the sys_language_uid of news to -1 in TYPO3 9?

Tags: localization, multilingual, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I want to use some news across multiple languages, but currently I can't choose -1 (all languages) via TYPO3 backend. Furthermore I can only choose between sys_language_uid 0 to 3, which are the uids of my configured languages.

If I take a look at the TCA configuration of the news model (tx_news_domain_model_news.php). Then I can see that -1, all languages still exists there.

```
'sys_language_uid' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'special' => 'languages',
            'items' => [
                [
                    'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
                    -1,
                    'flags-multiple'
                ],
            ],
            'default' => 0,
        ]
],
```

but it is not not available for me:

[image]

Do I miss a specific language setting to enable this option or how I can enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by another extension which have removed this -1 entry.